# Trying to limit string to 8000 characters before using data and I get nulls returned

Tags: powershell, substring, select-object

Writing some code to do an insert from rest API into database.  One of the fields needs to be limited to 8000 characters which I am having trouble doing.

Tried lots of googling.

```
$searchResultsResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $searchResultsUri -ContentType application/json -Header $requestHeader
$dt = $searchResultsResponse.fields | Select -Property @{label="val";expression={$_.value.Substring(0,8000)}},displayName,name
```

Expecting the character length to be limited to so many characters but it returns a null value

Comment: [1] if you leave off the `| Select-Object` do you have a property named `.Value`? [2] if you perform the `.SubString()` directly on the object, does it work? [3] do you get any error messages at all?

Comment: Can you please share more details. what is $searchResultsUri and $requestHeader .I can  try to generate an error on  my machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do an **if** statement as `.substring(Start Index, Length)` will throw an error if there are less than `Length` characters:

```
$(if($_.Length -gt 8000){$_.Substring(0,8000)}else{$_})
```

Check if `Length` is greater than (`-gt`) 8k, then use `substring()`, otherwise send as is:

```
$searchResultsResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $searchResultsUri -ContentType application/json -Header $requestHeader 
$dt = $searchResultsResponse.fields | Select -Property @{label="val";expression={$(if($_.Length -gt 8000){$_.Substring(0,8000)}else{$_})}},displayName,name
```